# Union Different Field type as String

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have `2 tables` in `GCP BigQuery Table`.

```
Table 1 has 4 Attributes

Name (STRING)
ID (INTEGER)
Org Num (STRING)
Country Code (INTEGER)
```

`Table 2` also have 4 Attributes

```
Name (STRING)
ID (STRING)
Org Num (INTEGER)
Country Code (STRING)
```

Now I am trying to merge or **UNION** these 2 tables' values, so I am trying like this -

```
SELECT * FROM 'project1.Dataset1.Table1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 'project1.Dataset1.Table2'
```

But it returns be error cause in these 2 tables the fields are different types. Do anyone knows if there is any way I can query these 2 tables and save all values as `STRING` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       CAST(id AS STRING) AS id,
       [Org Num],
       CAST([Country Code] AS STRING) AS [Country Code]
FROM 'project1.Dataset1.Table1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
       id,
       CAST([Org Num] AS STRING) AS [Org Num],
       [Country Code] 
FROM 'project1.Dataset1.Table2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the integer columns to strings in your query